# Resize square image proportionally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am having issues getting an image to scale properly to my `UITableCell`.  I have a large copy of the image and want to scale by a variable height cell.  It is a square image that is x by x.

```
UIImageView *pw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

[pw setImage:img];
pw.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
pw.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - img.size.width, cell.frame.origin.y,
                             ?, cell.frame.size.height);

[cell.contentView addSubview:pw];
```

The issue is I am not sure what value to put for the `?` parameter (the image width) since it can scale depending on the height of the cell its in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the width of your image depends on the height of the cell you could make it proportional to it. For example,

- If the width is the same as the height, make "?" equal to cell.frame.size.height
- If the width is 2X the height, make "?" equal to cell.frame.size.height * 2
- If the width is half the height, make "?" equal to cell.frame.size.height/2
- etc...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Duh....I can't believe I didn't think of that...just set it equal to the `cell.frame.size.height`!  Thanks

Comment: Strangely, I posted the solution first.

Comment: You should only get the cell's height after it has been prepared. That means after cellRowAtIndexPath in the willShowTableViewCell method. This is especially true if your table cell height is variable.

Answer (score 1):

If it should be a square, put the same in the x direction as the y direction:

```
CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - img.size.width, 
       cell.frame.origin.y,
       cell.frame.size.height, 
       cell.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use Auto Layout it is easy to do this with height and width constraints on the image view. 
One of them is equal to the other one. 
Adjust the constant of the other one. 
Set needsLayout. Maybe animate.